# Authentication required (unexpectedly)

Tags: mailkit

My vb.net code uses Mailkit to send emails via my ionos server.

```
Dim cl As New SmtpClient

cl.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf AcceptAllCertifications

cl.Connect(email_host, 25, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.None)

cl.Send(de_mimemessage)
```

The code works fine normally but occasionally (perhaps once every few hundred times) I get the following error at the connect part of the code:

> Authentication required

what can I do differently so that this error never occurs?

Here is the stacktrace...

```
(MimeMessage message, MailboxAddress mailbox, SmtpResponse response)
   at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.<MailFromAsync>d__88.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.<SendAsync>d__99.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.Send(FormatOptions options, MimeMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ITransferProgress progress)
   at MailKit.MailTransport.Send(MimeMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ITransferProgress progress)
   at marketing_email_plus_removals.send_email(Boolean in_test, String in_email, String in_postcode) in E:\kunden\homepages\14\d650565413\www\marketing_email_plus_removals.aspx.vb:line 547
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get an "Authentication Required" exception, it means that the server won't let you send that message until you authenticate.

When that happens, call:

```
cl.Authenticate ("username", "password");
```

Comment: If I change to the following code then the same server gives the error; even though it claims to support TLS  -  'The SMTP server does not support authentication'   `cl.Connect("smtp.ionos.co.uk", 587, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTls); 
 cl.Authenticate("my username", "my password");`

Comment: Then I guess you need to use a different server.